# Which module hook to use for CRUD operations on custom table?

Tags: 7, forms, database, hooks

I have used `hook_schema()` in my module to create a custom table in the Drupal database - the data is unrelated to anything in Drupal.

I would like administrators to be able to insert, update etc. records in this custom table. I had thought to use the function `hook_form()` for this, but upon closer inspection this hook relates back to nodes. My custom table has no relation to nodes.

Is there a different function I should be using?

Comment: First, there is not one hook for that. Second, what Drupal version are you using? Because form api changed quite a lot.

Comment: My module is for Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call any special hooks. You just need to create menu items for `insert/edit/delete/list` of data.

[Here](http://ataraza.com/create-an-example-crud-module-in-drupal-7/) is an example module that create basic crud using custom table.

If you want to create listing with views instead of custom listing callback function you will need to use `view_api` and `hook_views_data` in your module for that.